# mouseover making table cell go nuts

Tags: jquery, html, css

i have a table with three cells whose widths are 30%, 40%, and 30% respectively. the table itself has a width of 25% of its container, which can vary from 1024px to 400px.

the first cell is a button that says GALLERY. on hover (of the td) its text changes to a "<", (through jquery).

the problem is that when the table is compressed (ie: the container is smaller than, say, 600px), and i hover over the GALLERY button, the width of the cell changes (because its html is now just an "<"). this causes the mouseover area to be pushed away and the cell to rapidly switch back and forth between hover states.

the width of the cell is defined, there's no padding or margins, and overflow:hidden is on.

anyone have any ideas on how to fix this? i get the same issue with the third cell too.

this only happens in firefox.

screenshots:

- normal: https://i.stack.imgur.com/6ZRYy.png
- hover: https://i.stack.imgur.com/HHkwA.png

edit:

jquery

```
$('td.back').hover(
    function() {
        $(this).empty().html('<').addClass("hover");
    },
    function() {
        $(this).empty().html('GALLERY').removeClass("hover");
    });
```

html

```
<table id="toolbar" style="display:none;">
      <tr>
        <td class="back" onclick="<?php 
          if ($gallery_id == "2") echo "goToGallery(1);";
          else echo "goToIndex();";
          ?>">GALLERY
      </td>
```

css

```
#toolbar td {
font-family:'helvetica',sans-serif;
font-size:11px;
color:white;
text-align:center;
cursor:pointer;
overflow:hidden;
-webkit-font-smoothing:antialiased;
}

#toolbar td.back {
width:30%;
}

#toolbar td.back:hover {
color:#e61b23;
}
```

Comment: Sounds like a typo to me. Can you post code?

Comment: yes, i've updated the original post with code

Comment: Could you put it in a demo (jsfiddle.net)? That way I could see exactly what's happening.

Comment: yup, i think you're right and there must be a typo because i made a fiddle and the issue wasn't there. i'll find it. thanks for the help! http://jsfiddle.net/5V3SR/6/

Answer (score 0):

It's because the table isn't a fixed width so the td (and table) gets smaller when you change the cell contents to "<". I.e., your td is 30% the width of a table whose width changes with it's content. So it might start as 30% of 100px wide table, then change to 30% of a 40px wide table (for example, those aren't real px values), which knocks your content back and forth with the width changes. Set the table or the td to a fixed width and you'll be all good.
You could also put a fixed width div inside the td so that the cell can expand or contract but keep the content from bouncing around.

Answer (score 0):

I agree with bbird version of what is going on. As a fix, I'd suggest adding the following CSS attribute to the table:

```
table-layout: fixed;
```